# Google plus share different content on same website

Tags: javascript, google-plus, social-networking

I have a single page website with url change thanks to Backbone Router.

The thing is I need to share content of the page on G+ with different content / image url / Title.

I can't figure out how to do it.

For Facebook I use the User agent check to set the good meta propoerties when Facebook crawls the website, but with G+ I can't find any documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google+ uses the following UA.

```
Google (+https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/)
```

[Source](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/)

Comment: Thanks, It seems to work, but I still don't have the description when I share the page. I guess it's because of Google cache ?

Comment: Google will potentially cache snippets for as long as your pages caching headers allow but usually not for longer than a couple hours/days.